# Azure API Management does not match incoming request url to uri template when contains encoded hash

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Due to certain customer requirements our Azure API Management must be able to handle GET requests with URLs containing hash signs (#). Alas, I can't find a way to make it work.

So, let's imagine there is a following url template:
`/products/{id}/items`, where `{id}` is a string which may contain #.

What I did is that {id} is encoded when called from the web application, so example call to the APIM is:
`https://contoso.apim.com/products/some%23id/items`, where %23 is encoded # sign.

Such url is handled correctly when used against actual API (which, btw. is a .net core 3 api deployed to Service Fabric cluster), however when used via APIM management, request returns **404 FABRIC_E_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST** error.
If I were to replace %23 with any other encoded value, e.g. %20, uri template would be correctly matched and hit underlying API.

After running some APIM request traces, I can definitely confirm that url thats being forwarded to the backend from APIM is not trimmed or changed in any way.

Any suggestion how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: how you set backend via `set-backend-service` policy?

Comment: How did you request the APIM url and the actual API ? In postman ? or in chrome browser ? or anyother way ? And did you do any configuration in APIM policy ?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan, I do not set any - its using base API address specified in the configuration

Comment: @HuryShen, I tested it from both postman and web app (local and deployed in azure, browsed in Chrome)

Comment: I test it in postman, chrome browser and HttpClient code, they all work fine. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkQKi.png) is a screenshot I test in postman, is your test in postman like this ?

Comment: Yes, I use the same set of headers as you are for the test, with no success.
Anyway, it is a good news that it is working for you - it means its doable at least ;)

Comment: @HuryShen, do you use any non-default policies in your configuration?

Comment: In my opinion, I don't think the problem was caused by APIM. I guess it may be caused by your backend api. Is there any other configuration(such as apim policy) or operation between the APIM api and your backend api ?

Comment: I didn't use any policy, I just configure the apim api like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Ew1.png).

Comment: No, nothing at all. APIM is configured to redirect request to service fabric reverse proxy endpoint and thats it. Anyway, thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Could you please have a try with double encode: `some%2523id` ?

Comment: Still getting 404_FABRIC_E_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST

Comment: Hi @szachmat May I know if your problem was solved ? If you solved it by yourself, could you please post an answer below for other communities reference.

Comment: Hi @HuryShen, I ended up contacting MS support. Once it's resolved I will post an answer to the question.

Comment: @HuryShen, if you are still interested, finally there is an answer from MS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time, but eventually MS team found that this is a bug in Service Fabric reverse proxy that will be fixed in the near future.
The workaround I had to use involved moving parameters from route to query parameter where # encoding is handled correctly.

**31.03.2021 Update**:
Service Fabric 7.2 CU7 has been released, containing fix for described issue.